# less cases or fewer cases

Tags: grammar

"So, the reason that we're having less cases now is because of the lockdown measures that we have implemented" [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=libhd7y8us0] [4:50]

Normally I would say definitely "fewer cases" because "case" is a countable noun. But I googled it and it seems that "less cases" is commonly used. Are there any other similar "abnormalities" or shall we say "exceptions"?

Comment: *Fewer*, unless there are so many cases that they’re treated as a massed set.

Comment: Even native speakers are often not aware of the rule about using _fewer_ with a countable noun. To quote Doctor Johnson - "Ignorance, madam, pure ignorance."

Comment: @KateBunting There is no rule about using *fewer* with a countable noun. It was invented by just one man, and even that one man expressly labeled it as his personal stylistic recommendation rather than a rule, which it is not.

Comment: Thank you guys!